# Get max date from multiple columns which also holds #N/A

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to get max date from multiple columns which also holds #N/A value generated from vlook up.

The issue is when I use MAX(B1:B3), it returns #N/A, if any cell holds #N/A.

How to get a date if a cell holds #N/A Value.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `AGGREGATE()` with `Options` 6 which will ignore error values. Try-

```
=AGGREGATE(4,6,B2:C2)
```

Here `FUNCTION` argument `4` represent `MAX()` function.